# Mqtt node connected to multiple router

Tags: mqtt, raspberry-pi

I have NodeMcu which I wanted to work as MQTT node, and I will have 50 nodes which will connect to routers(total 3) where these routers are connected to the main router through LAN.

For a broker, I will use Rpi 3b+.

So can I use local MQTT broker?
If not

1. What should I do? a public MQTT broker?
2. other better option?

Comment: you should be able to use a local MQTT broker

Comment: Why do you think you can't use your own local broker?